# Event Handler Gets lost on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, bootstrap-modal

I would like to be able to bind a delegate to a button's Click event using the += syntax. But the event handler gets lost after postback. Here are some more details.

I am creating a web control for generic modal functionality. I want to be able to put the control on the page and have it display a Bootstrap modal dialog. The .ascx file has the bootstrap markup with a couple of Literal controls, for the body and header, and a couple of Button controls.

I declared a public method for the control with the following signature:

```
public void ShowModal(
  string Title, 
  string Body, 
  string Button1Text, 
  string Button2Text, 
  delegate Button1Action, 
  delegate button2Action){
     Title.Text=Title;
     Body.Text=Body;
     Button1.Click+=Button1Action;
     Button1.Text=Button1Text;
     Button2.Click += Button2Action;
     Button2.Text=Button2.Text;
     var script = "$('#MyModal').modal();";
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Modal), "modal", script, true);
  }
```

This will register a startup script in javascript which displays the modal. Everything works fine, except the binding of event handler delegate to button. It seems to get lost during the post back page lifecycle.

I also tried replacing the delegate parameter with "Action" type:

```
Action<Object,EventArgs> Button1Action
```

Comment: Do you mean that button events are lost after Postback?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It seems that the event handler needs to be rebound on every postback.